# Remove array duplicates but keep original

Tags: powershell

I have an array:

```
Name
----
hi
hello
hello
```

I would like to get rid of all duplicates - but keep at least one original. so the output should look like

```
Name
----
hi
hello
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Select-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) -Unique

> Specifies that if a subset of the input objects has identical
>   properties and values, only a single member of the subset will be
>   selected.
>
> This parameter is case-sensitive. As a result, strings that differ
>   only in character casing are considered to be unique.

Example 5: Select unique characters from an array

```
PS C:\>"a","b","c","a","a","a" | Select-Object -Unique

a
b
c
```

This command uses the `Unique` parameter of `Select-Object` to get unique characters from an array of characters.

Comment: I've tried using that - when i do it only gives me hi - it removes the objects that appear more than once.

Comment: okay - so i figured it out. The reason why it wasn't working was because it was including the header in the array - i needed to call the array header specifically before the select-object -unique would work. 

$array.name | select-object -unique

Answer (score 2):

There is a few ways you can do this. If it is for a script, I recommend using full command names instead of alias's.

```
     $name = ( "hi", "hello", "hello" )
     $name | Sort-Object -Unique
     $name | Get-Unique
```

For fun, lets dive deep.

```
Get-Member -InputObject $name
```

This will give us a read out of the different properties and methods of an array, such as the Length Property. Let's try using these as dot operators.

```
$name.Length
```

There we have the length of the array.

I'm not a genius at this. I just know how to use the built in help.

```
Get-Help *arrays* -full
Get-Help *about*
Get-Help Get-Member -full
Get-Help Get-Command
```

Have fun and explore!

Answer (score 0):

```
$youarray="element1", "element2", "element1"

#solution with unique select
$youarray | select -Unique


#solution with group by
$youarray | group {$_} | select Name
```